# Opening an Excel file without filename using xlrd

Tags: python, filenames, xlrd

I am developing a Python script for work that will open an Excel file from a particular directory without knowing what the filename is. currently I am opening the file like this. Also opening particular sheet.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\New folder\EXCELUPLOAD.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet3")
```

I want to open the file without giving its name, either using its extension or using first few letters etc.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\New folder\_.xls or Exce_')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet3")
```

Is there any way around to do this?

Comment: You could write some separate code that gets the filename from that directory based on your conditions and then passes that to `open_workbook`.

Comment: Actually, I'm a new to python so don't know how to do it. Can you please give an example to understand this better?

Comment: What if there are a few files with that extension? And that same prefix?

Comment: @Tomerikoo There will be no other files as I am storing only one file in that particular directory. I just want to know how I can do this.

Comment: Check the duplicate. Assuming your directory has one file, list "all" files and choose the first (only) one...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for the reply but I just want to know that can I open the file only with extension or using some letters with xlrd.

Comment: No. But you can do it with `glob` to find your file - `for file in glob.glob("*.xls"):` - and then open it with xlrd

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it using glob.